# WCF "target principal name is incorrect" in Blazor Server app

Tags: wcf, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying call a WCF service (AX 2012) from my blazor app. I've added the reference under connected services (Visual Studio 2019) and the code generation worked. But when I call it the same way as in a WPF app I get the exception "target principal name is incorrect".

All information I can find refers to editing the app.config file. How can I fix this error using code changes or the dotnet core settings files? (I assume the appsettings.json)

I assumed authentication in the WPF app works simply by piggybacking off the logged in windows user but inspecting the config file I see this:

```
  <endpoint address="net.tcp://server:8201/DynamicsAx/Services/WorkerSG"
      binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_HcmWorkerImportService"
      contract="ServiceAXEmployees.HcmWorkerImportService" name="NetTcpBinding_HcmWorkerImportService">
    <identity>
      <userPrincipalName value="svcax.aos@ourdoma.in" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
```

Comment: @HenkHolterman I've added what I know about the authentication part. If additional information is needed please let me know.

Comment: Maybe you can try removing `<identity>
       <userPrincipalName value="svcax.aos@ourdoma.in" />
     </identity>`.

Comment: @LanHuang: That's the version that works. What I need is some way to set the principal when you don't have a web.config